# Need to "merge" blocks of records in query into one, depending on other query columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following db scheme.

`CREATE TABLE Twix.dbo.Sensors
    (Id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    Location nvarchar(260) NOT NULL);`

```
CREATE TABLE Twix.dbo.Visitors
(Id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
Name nvarchar(260) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Twix.dbo.Visits(Id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
SensorId int CONSTRAINT FK__Visits__Sensor__239E FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Sensors(Id),
VisitorId int CONSTRAINT FK__Visits__Visitors__4DCF FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Visitors(Id),
InTime datetime NOT NULL,
OutTime datetime NOT NULL);
```

InTime-OutTime periods in Visits table could be intersected. I.e. parts of real visits.  For example,

`SELECT VisitorId, InTime, OutTime FROM Visits ORDER BY VisitorId, InTime`

```
1   2011-02-09 15:26:59.173 2011-02-09 15:29:22.097
1   2011-02-09 15:28:40.530 2011-02-09 15:29:52.737
1   2011-02-09 15:30:10.577 2011-02-09 16:17:58.967
1   2011-02-09 19:09:23.057 2011-02-09 19:10:57.493
1   2011-02-09 19:12:16.087 2011-02-09 19:13:27.493
1   2011-02-14 15:08:46.333 2011-02-14 15:26:42.433
2   2011-02-09 17:55:42.390 2011-02-09 18:52:03.780
2   2011-02-09 18:10:56.727 2011-02-09 18:11:57.493
2   2011-02-09 21:47:15.650 2011-02-09 21:48:38.783
2   2011-02-09 21:50:18.337 2011-02-09 21:55:26.777
3   2011-02-09 17:12:58.103 2011-02-09 19:51:59.697
3   2011-02-09 22:27:52.073 2011-02-09 23:03:24.753
3   2011-02-09 23:02:51.177 2011-02-10 09:51:14.890
3   2011-02-14 15:27:42.270 2011-02-14 15:42:31.107
3   2011-02-14 15:43:37.320 2011-02-14 18:45:26.163
4   2011-02-09 21:07:51.030 2011-02-09 21:51:02.880
4   2011-02-09 22:42:52.660 2011-02-09 23:21:13.830
4   2011-02-09 23:23:08.563 2011-02-09 23:35:12.847
4   2011-02-09 23:36:05.120 2011-02-09 23:59:02.813
4   2011-02-10 05:58:44.103 2011-02-10 05:59:55.867
4   2011-02-12 08:29:36.620 2011-02-12 09:51:18.510
4   2011-02-12 13:13:42.650 2011-02-12 14:06:01.473
5   2011-02-10 06:48:52.717 2011-02-10 07:37:04.870
5   2011-02-10 06:50:31.067 2011-02-10 06:52:20.877
5   2011-02-10 06:52:36.273 2011-02-10 06:53:36.523
5   2011-02-10 06:59:11.790 2011-02-10 07:00:34.867
5   2011-02-10 08:36:39.563 2011-02-10 08:46:14.760
5   2011-02-10 12:47:05.567 2011-02-10 12:48:05.860
5   2011-02-10 12:49:19.590 2011-02-10 13:09:27.880
5   2011-02-10 12:49:25.733 2011-02-10 12:59:59.883
5   2011-02-10 12:55:23.460 2011-02-10 12:56:23.507
```

I need to get "completed visits", i.e. merge all visits for concrete vistor, if visits are intersecting, or time difference between them less than 10 min (i.e. "InTime of visit2" - "OutTime of visit1" < 10 min).

In C# it looks like:

`private IEnumerable Merge(IEnumerable visits, uint holeInterval)`

```
    {
        var vlist = new LinkedList<Visit>(visits.OrderBy(o => o.InTime));
        var result = new List<Visit>();
        while (vlist.Count > 1)
        {
            Visit a = vlist.First.Value; vlist.RemoveFirst();
            Visit b = vlist.First.Value; vlist.RemoveFirst();
            var r = Visit.Merge(a, b, holeInterval); // Merges two visits
            if (r != null) { vlist.AddFirst(r); }
            else { result.Add(a); vlist.AddFirst(b); }
        }
        result.Add(vlist.First.Value);
        return result;
    }
public IEnumerable<Visit> ListCompleteVisits()
    {
        var result = new List<Visit>();
        var queryResult = from visits in this.repository.ListVisits()
                          group visits by visits.Visitor.Id into vgroup
                          select Merge(vgroup, this.holeInterval);
        foreach (var v in queryResult)
        {
            result.AddRange(v);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I tried, and get the following:

`DECLARE @holeInterval int
    SET @holeInterval = 10`

```
SELECT t.RowNumber, t.VisitorId, t.InTime, t.OutTime, t.BInMinusAOut,
    (SELECT MIN(InTime) FROM Visits AS D
     WHERE VisitorId NOT IN (select VisitorId from Visits group by VisitorId having COUNT(*) = 1)
     AND D.InTime <= t.InTime and D.VisitorId = t.VisitorId 
     AND t.RowNumber >  /*here should be max rownumber greater than holeinterval*/
    ) AS MinInTime
FROM
    (SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY VisitorId, InTime ASC) AS RowNumber, 
     VisitorId, InTime, OutTime,       
     DATEDIFF(MI,InTime,
            (SELECT MIN(InTime) FROM Visits AS B
             WHERE B.InTime > A.InTime and A.VisitorId = B. VisitorId
            )) AS BInMinusAIn,
     DATEDIFF(MI,OutTime,
            (SELECT MIN(InTime) FROM Visits AS B
             WHERE B.InTime > A.InTime and A.VisitorId = B. VisitorId
            ))) AS BInMinusAOut
FROM Visits AS A
WHERE VisitorId NOT IN (select VisitorId from Visits group by VisitorId having COUNT(*) = 1)
) t
/*WHERE t.BInMinusAOut > @holeInterval OR t.BInMinusAOut IS NULL*/
ORDER BY VisitorId, InTime

1   1   2011-02-09 15:26:59.173 2011-02-09 15:28:22.097 0
2   1   2011-02-09 15:28:40.530 2011-02-09 15:29:52.737 1
3   1   2011-02-09 15:30:10.577 2011-02-09 16:17:58.967 9
4   1   2011-02-09 16:26:44.810 2011-02-09 16:51:46.423 20
5   1   2011-02-09 17:11:57.633 2011-02-09 17:13:20.680 2
6   1   2011-02-09 17:15:35.727 2011-02-09 17:18:48.493 -2
7   1   2011-02-09 17:16:12.230 2011-02-09 17:42:47.867 3
8   1   2011-02-09 17:45:43.793 2011-02-09 17:52:10.860 3
9   1   2011-02-09 17:55:31.127 2011-02-09 20:13:22.743 -109
10  1   2011-02-09 18:24:00.427 2011-02-09 18:32:12.033 2
11  1   2011-02-09 18:34:15.877 2011-02-09 18:37:19.770 2
12  1   2011-02-09 18:39:46.440 2011-02-09 18:48:16.800 2
13  1   2011-02-09 18:50:59.270 2011-02-09 20:03:47.550 -54
14  1   2011-02-09 19:09:23.057 2011-02-09 19:10:57.493 2
15  1   2011-02-09 19:12:16.087 2011-02-09 19:13:27.493 48
```

Now I need to "merge" 1st-4th into 2011-02-09 15:26:59.173 - 2011-02-09 16:51:46.423
                      5th-15h into 2011-02-09 17:11:57.633 - 2011-02-09 20:13:22.743
This means, that I have to take min InTime in rows, which is between current and the last, where MinInTime > @holeInterval, and max OutTime for those range too.

`I.e. result:`

```
1   2011-02-09 15:26:59.173 2011-02-09 16:51:46.423
1   2011-02-09 17:11:57.633 2011-02-09 20:13:22.743
```

Thank's.

Comment: It would really, really help to know what database you are working with.  I know how to do this in both MySQL and Oracle, but the techniques you use are entirely unrelated.

Comment: but you know as tag is tsql which means it is MS SQL Server

Comment: @baalazamon: Good point, in which case the only approach I can think of would be to use cursors.  Since I've never used MS SQL Server, I'll let someone else write that up.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do everything in one big select statement. 
Write a stored procedure that creates a temporary table by using `Select INTO #temp` syntax. Then modify/append the temporary table. Then finally, select from the temp table as an output. The performance will be good and you can move on.

Comment: +1 as, while this may not be the most elegant solution, it would get the job done and it's probably better to have a good solution now than a perfect solution some day.  Of course, other wise people on Stackd Overflow have provided excellent solutions already!

Answer (score 1):

The query was written with Common Table Expressions to make it a bit clearer what is happening, but you can just `UNION ALL` the 2 queries for exactly the same result.

What is happening in the query:

### OverlappingVisits

the table is joined by expanding the InTime and OutTime by 10 minutes. This will select all the overlapping Vists from the data set. Then the `CASE` statement is used to choose the lowest value from the 2 overlapping timespans as InTime and the highest value for the OutTime. Since we still get multiple results by doing that a groupby with min/max is done to filter out the minimum and maximum timestamps of the complete resultset.

### NonOverlappingVisits

Similar to the overlapping visits the timespans are expanded by 10 minutes on either side to find the overlapping parts and matched with `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

```
Declare @holeinterval int

SET @holeinterval = 10
;WITH OverlappingVisits (VisitorId, InTime, OutTime)
AS (select v1.VisitorId
     , InTime =  MIN(CASE WHEN v1.InTime < v2.InTime THEN v1.InTime ELSE v2.InTime END) 
     , OutTime = MAX(CASE WHEN v1.OutTime < v2.OutTime THEN v2.OutTime ELSE v1.OutTime END) 
FROM Visits v1
  INNER JOIN Visits v2
  ON v1.VisitorId = v2.VisitorId 
  AND (v1.InTime BETWEEN dateadd(minute, -@holeinterval, v2.InTime) AND dateadd(minute, @holeinterval, v2.OutTime)
  OR v1.OutTime BETWEEN dateadd(minute, @holeinterval, v2.InTime) AND dateadd(minute, @holeinterval, v2.OutTime))
  AND v1.Id <> v2.Id
GROUP BY v1.VisitorId),
NonOverlappingVisits (VisitorId, InTime, OutTime)
AS (
SELECT v1.VisitorId
     ,  v1.InTime 
     ,  v1.OutTime 
FROM Visits v1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
  FROM Visits v2
  WHERE v1.VisitorId = v2.VisitorId 
  AND (v1.InTime BETWEEN dateadd(minute, -@holeinterval, v2.InTime) AND dateadd(minute, @holeinterval, v2.OutTime)
  OR v1.OutTime BETWEEN dateadd(minute, @holeinterval, v2.InTime) AND dateadd(minute, @holeinterval, v2.OutTime))
  AND v1.Id <> v2.Id))
SELECT *
FROM OverlappingVisits
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM NonOverlappingVisits
ORDER BY VisitorId, InTime, OutTime
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH
Visits_tuned AS (
  /* adding some helper columns */
  SELECT
    VisitorId,
    InTime,
    OutTime,
    OutTimeDelayed = DATEADD(minute, 10, OutTime),
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VisitorId
                                ORDER BY InTime, OutTime),
    VisitId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VisitorId, InTime, OutTime)
  FROM Visits
),

Visits_starts AS (
  /* spotting the starting points of the 'merged' visits */
  SELECT DISTINCT
    v1.VisitId,
    IsStart = 1 - CASE WHEN v2.VisitId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  FROM Visits_tuned v1
    LEFT JOIN Visits_tuned v2
      ON v1.InTime BETWEEN v2.InTime AND v2.OutTimeDelayed
        AND v1.VisitorId = v2.VisitorId AND v1.rownum <> v2.rownum
),

Visits_rec AS (
  /* basically, selecting the original data, but with
     InTime values replaced by the starting InTimes */
  SELECT
    VisitId,
    VisitorId,
    InTime,
    OutTime
  FROM Visits_tuned
  WHERE VisitId = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    v.VisitId,
    v.VisitorId,
    IntTime = CASE
      WHEN v.VisitorId = r.VisitorId AND
           s.IsStart = 0 AND r.InTime < v.InTime
        THEN r.InTime
      ELSE v.InTime
    END,
    v.OutTime
  FROM Visits_tuned v
    INNER JOIN Visits_rec r ON v.VisitId = r.VisitId + 1
    INNER JOIN Visits_starts s ON v.VisitId = s.VisitId
)

/* main select; just grouping by visitor and in-time */
SELECT
  VisitorId,
  InTime,
  OutTime = MAX(OutTime)
FROM Visits_rec
GROUP BY VisitorId, InTime
ORDER BY 1, 2
```