# Merge two or more rows in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2000

Suppose my table contains the following information:

```
row | ID  |       date1          |        date2            | place   | value
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  1  |  2011-01-23 05:33:21 |    2011-01-23 06:43:10  |    A    |     5
2   |  1  |  2011-01-23 06:44:21 |    2011-01-23 07:13:28  |    A    |     4
3   |  1  |  2011-01-23 07:14:21 |    2011-01-23 07:27:28  |    A    |     4
4   |  1  |  2011-01-23 08:30:11 |    2011-01-23 09:56:45  |    A    |     6
5   |  1  |  2011-01-23 09:58:21 |    2011-01-23 10:43:26  |    B    |     8
6   |  2  |  2011-01-23 05:33:21 |    2011-01-23 06:43:21  |    A    |     3
```

I want to merge just like row 1 and row 2 way that as below.(there are so many rows in the table like above) The condition is `DATEDIFF(minute, row1.date2, row2.date1) < 10 and row1.place = row2.place`

```
row | ID  |       date1          |        date2          |  place   | value
=======================================================================
1   |  1  |  2011-01-23 05:33:21 |   2011-01-23 07:27:28 |     A    |    13
2   |  1  |  2011-01-23 08:30:11 |   2011-01-23 09:56:45 |     A    |    6
3   |  1  |  2011-01-23 09:58:21 |   2011-01-23 10:43:26 |     B    |    8
4   |  2  |  2011-01-23 05:33:21 |   2011-01-23 06:43:21 |     A    |    3
```

please help me to select the above result from my table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please insert pipes "|" in your data to make it easier to read and put each row of data on its own line.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018403/need-to-merge-blocks-of-records-in-query-into-one-depending-on-other-query-col) your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table
   select 
      row, id, date1, date2, place, sum(value)
   from table
   where (your date diff condition)
   group by row, id, date1, date2, place
```

I think this should work.. :)

Comment: thank for ur reply but there isn't a row column and I want to select those value from my table to view. I want to merge two rows accordings to my condition and date2 should change as i mention above as  well as value.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!